# Sum a list of lists to get a sum list Python

Tags: python, function

I'm trying to create a define a helper function that sums a list of lists to get a sum list.

For example:

```
[[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]]
```

Would come out as:

```
[4,7,10]
```

I found this on another post to work:

```
[sum(i) for i in zip(*listoflists)]
```

I need to to translate this into a defined function. This is what I have so far but it's not working.

```
def addhours(listoflists):
    for list in zip(*listoflists):
        newsum = sum (list)
return newsum
```

Comment: Just `return [sum(i) for i in zip(*listoflists)]`

Answer (score 3):

Just put the list comprehension inside the function. (with `return`)

```
>>> def addhours(listoflists):
...     return [sum(lst) for lst in zip(*listoflists)]
...
>>> addhours([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
[4, 7, 10]
```

### Why your code does not work?

```
def addhours(listoflists):
    for list in zip(*listoflists):
        newsum = sum (list)  # <---- This statement overwrites newsum
    return newsum # returns the last sum.
```

You need a list to hold sums as items.

```
def addhours(listoflists):
    result = []
    for lst in zip(*listoflists):
        result.append(sum(lst)) # Append to the list instead of overwriting.
    return result
```

BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name. It shadows builtin function [`list`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list).

Comment: Nice. How should I modify this to make it a function that calculates the mean? So in the example above, the output would be `[4/3,7/3,10/3]`?

Comment: @user3287712, Replace the return statement as: `return [sum(lst)/len(lst) for lst in zip(*listoflists)]`, If you use Python 2.x, you need to convert one of the value to float: `return [float(sum(lst))/len(lst) for lst in zip(*listoflists)]`

Answer (score 3):

Since the function is  quite small, you could also use an anonymous definition:

```
>>> addhours = lambda l: [sum(i) for i in zip(*l)]
>>> addhours([[1,2,3],[1,2,3],[2,3,4]])
>>> [4,7,10]
```